# how to open specific folders images using android default gallery showing error

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am using the following code to open images from a particular directory.. the problem is it works fine for my galaxy ace... But i am not able to open it on other phones..
I have also attached the stacktrace.
 Please help..
Thank you :)

```
private void startScan() {
        Log.d(Login.TAG, "Scan Started");
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }

        conn = new MediaScannerConnection(this, this);
        conn.connect();
    }

    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        conn.scanFile(SCAN_PATH, FILE_TYPE);
    }

    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        try {
            if (uri != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
            conn = null;
        }
    }
```

0

```
5-05 13:11:46.990: E/JavaBinder(3437): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
05-05 13:11:46.990: E/JavaBinder(3437): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://media/external/images/media/8899 }
05-05 13:11:46.990: E/JavaBinder(3437):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1580)
05-05 13:11:46.990: E/JavaBinder(3437):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
05-05 13:11:46.990: E/JavaBinder(3437):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)
05-05 13:11:46.990: E/JavaBinder(3437):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
05-05 13:11:46.990: E/JavaBinder(3437):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3617)
05-05 13:11:46.990: E/JavaBinder(3437):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3585)
05-05 13:11:46.990: E/JavaBinder(3437):     at com.youbank.NewMenu.onScanCompleted(NewMenu.java:127)
05-05 13:11:46.990: E/JavaBinder(3437):     at android.media.MediaScannerConnection$1.scanCompleted(MediaScannerConnection.java:56)
05-05 13:11:46.990: E/JavaBinder(3437):     at android.media.IMediaScannerListener$Stub.onTransact(IMediaScannerListener.java:60)
05-05 13:11:46.990: E/JavaBinder(3437):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
05-05 13:11:46.990: E/JavaBinder(3437):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your **device  does not have an application capable of viewing that local file**. Try downloading apps from appStore related to view images.

I am answering this with ref to logcat details you have provided.(May or may not be right answer)

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually for the first time it is askng for choosing a action... i select gallery it opens... then if you try the button click again.... it throws the above exception..........